# How to send JSON data using SSL

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, ssl

I'm trying to send JSON data using socket, but get this error

> b'HTTP/0.9 413 Request Entity Too Large\r\nServer:
>   inets/5.10.2\r\nDate: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 18:19:38 GMT\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/html\r\nContent-Length: 202\r\n\r\n'

my code:

```
def single_contract(amount, service_key):

    current_date = datetime.now()
    fee = 0
    if amount > 10000.0:
        fee = amount * 0.01

    if os.path.exists('./Files/Point.txt'):
        with open('./Files/Point.txt') as opened_file:
            point_id = opened_file.read()

            json_data = dict()
            json_data["single_contract"] = dict()
            json_data["single_contract"]["point_id"] = point_id.strip()
            json_data["single_contract"]["datetime"] = datetime.strftime(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            json_data["single_contract"]["external_transaction_id"] = randint(999999999, 9999999999)
            json_data["single_contract"]["service_id"] = 1001351861392575516
            json_data["single_contract"]["amount"] = amount
            json_data["single_contract"]["service_key"] = service_key
            json_data["single_contract"]["fee"] = round(fee, 2)
            json_data["single_contract"]["params"] = None

        with open('./Files/sending_file.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            json.dump(json_data, json_file)

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
        sslcontext.load_verify_locations('./Files/ca-cert.pem')
        sslcontext.load_cert_chain(certfile='./Files/com-cert.pem',
                                   keyfile='./Files/com-key.pem')
        host = '***.***.***.***'
        port = ****
        ssl_socket = sslcontext.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
        ssl_socket.connect((host, port))

        with open('./Files/sending_file.json', mode='rb') as f:
            ssl_socket.sendfile(f)

        with open('./Files/answer.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as reply:
            reply.write(str(ssl_socket.recv()))

        ssl_socket.close()
        print('End of connection')

    else:
        print('No such file or directory.')
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: The indents in your code look screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending too much data.  You need to either decrease the size of what you are sending or, if you have control of the server, adjust it's settings to allow it to receive larger Https requests.

http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com/2013/09/nginx-error-413-request-entity-too-large.html

Comment: My data file size is 215 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't seem like much, but what you are receiving is an error generated from the server saying that what you sent is too large.  So even though it seems small, obviously the it's above the Server's maximum.  That is something that is configured on the Server.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to ask about the server's settings if they are ok.